# Can't get dialog with full width

Tags: android, android-dialog

I what bottom sliding panel in my app and for that I used custom dialog but there is some space both side of the dialog and at the bottom of the dialog.How can I remove that space?

Here is my code.

**Custom layout**

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:paddingTop="30dp"
android:paddingBottom="30dp">

//elements of the layout

</LinearLayout>
```

**Custom dialog JAVA**

```
public class BottomPanel {
Context context;

public BottomPanel(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public Dialog showDialog() {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.CustomDialog);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
    layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;

    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.bottom_sheet);
    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    return dialog;
}
}
```

[image: Here is a screenshot of custom dialog]

Comment: `dialog.getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);`

Comment: show all the bottom_sheet.xml file

Comment: Remove the padding of your parent layout ?

Comment: Nothing works. @JohnJoe

Comment: Tried it but no luck @vincrichaud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my research, default window background for dialog is [abc_dialog_material_background.xml](https://github.com/dandar3/android-support-v7-appcompat/blob/master/res/drawable/abc_dialog_material_background.xml)

```
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:insetLeft="16dp"
       android:insetTop="16dp"
       android:insetRight="16dp"
       android:insetBottom="16dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="@dimen/abc_dialog_corner_radius_material" />
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    </shape>
</inset>
```

That why you see the padding from each site when your dialog is showed. There are several ways to remove all padding from the dialog.

The easy way is set a color background for dialog's window background.

```
<style name="CustomDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Another way is creating a custom background for dialog named `background_dialog.xml`

```
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="@dimen/abc_dialog_corner_radius_material" />
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    </shape>
</inset>
```

Then set it as window background for your dialog in style.xml file.

```
<style name="CustomDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_dialog</item>
</style>
```